# How to display no duplicate records in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Does anyone know how can I display records that are not duplicated record inside results in SQL Server?

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm sure you want something more than 'select DISTINCT'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use distinct

`SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table`

Or use group by

`select field1,field2,field3 FROM table GROUP BY field1, field2, field3`

Comment: Keyfield,* ? What's the * for?

Answer (score 2):

If you really meant "***records that with no duplicate record*** ", i.e., every row that exists once, and only once, Try this:

```
  Select * From Table
  Group By [Here list all columns in Table]
  Having Count(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Another interpretation of the question.

```
SELECT *
FROM   yourtable t1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS
       (SELECT *
       FROM    yourtable t2
       WHERE   t1.col_to_match_for_duplicates=t2.col_to_match_for_duplicates
       AND     t1.primarykey                <> t2.primarykey
       )
```