# Select distinct rows from a query

Tags: sql-server, distinct

I have the following SQL Server Query:

```
select flujo, FECHA from El_Bosque 
where fecha between CONVERT(DATETIME,'2016-06-22 10:00:00',102) 
and CONVERT(DATETIME,'2016-06-28 00:00:00',102) and ( flujo >=0 ) 
order by fecha asc
```

It returns:

```
0.84    2016-06-22 10:00:00.000
0.84    2016-06-22 10:00:00.000
0.83    2016-06-22 10:15:00.000
0.83    2016-06-22 10:15:00.000
0.81    2016-06-22 10:30:00.000
0.81    2016-06-22 10:30:00.000
```

I would like to filter this query so I can only obtain distinct rows like this:

```
0.84    2016-06-22 10:00:00.000
0.83    2016-06-22 10:15:00.000
0.81    2016-06-22 10:30:00.000
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display no duplicate records in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330092/how-to-display-no-duplicate-records-in-sql-server)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try distinct keyword

```
select 
DISTINCT -- this keyword
flujo, FECHA from El_Bosque 
where fecha between CONVERT(DATETIME,'2016-06-22 10:00:00',102) 
and CONVERT(DATETIME,'2016-06-28 00:00:00',102) and ( flujo >=0 ) 
order by fecha asc
```

Also note that your query uses CONVERT function, you could be better off by writing like

```
DECLARE @t1 datetime
DECLARE @t2 datetime
SELECT @t1=CONVERT(DATETIME,'2016-06-22 10:00:00',102) , @t2=CONVERT(DATETIME,'2016-06-28 10:00:00',102) 
select 
DISTINCT -- this keyword
flujo, FECHA from El_Bosque 
where fecha between @t1 and @t2 and ( flujo >=0 ) 
order by fecha asc
```

Answer (score 1):

The `DISTINCT` keyword can be used to return only distinct (different) values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name,column_name
FROM table_name;
```

so your SQL query will look like

```
select DISTINCT  flujo, FECHA from El_Bosque 
where fecha between CONVERT(DATETIME,'2016-06-22 10:00:00',102) 
and CONVERT(DATETIME,'2016-06-28 00:00:00',102) and ( flujo >=0 ) 
order by fecha asc
```